# Reverting back to a previous kernel version

Tags: git, github

I have the kernel 2.6.38-utrace which is having the utrace support in it. I want to provide the utrace support for 2.6.29.6 kernel. My plan is to revert back the 2.6.38-utrace kernel to 2.6.29.6 using git and finding a diff between them and using it as a patch.

I am new to git. Can sombody kindly tell me the way to do this

Comment: keep asking the same question every other day won't help. 2.6.29 is too old, there are many changes ain't backportable. you need at least 2.9.36 or something.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ: I think 2.9.36 hasnot come till yet!! I should be 2.6.36

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the commit for Linux 2.6.29.6. Let's suppose it's `8e0ee4` (actually, that's 2.6.29):

```
git checkout 8e0ee4
```

Git will tell you you're now in a "detached HEAD state"; that's ok. Make a branch for your changes:

```
git checkout -b 2.6.29+utrace
```

Then use `git log`, GitHub or a GUI tool to find the commits that pertain to utrace support and use [`git cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) to lift those into the current branch.

Comment: That's not enough as there will be other changes that don't appear to be important but eventually a dependency will show them to be important. You might as well have the entire diff to pull in what is needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do a

```
git diff version1..version2
```

Hope this helps